# How to use Unity for dependency injection (simple example)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, unity-container

Consider this class with these two constructors:

```
public class DocumentService
{
    private IDocumentDbService documentDbService;
    private IDirectoryService directoryService;
    private IFileService fileService;

    // Constructor
    public DocumentService()
    {
          this.documentDbService = new DocumentDbService();
          this.directoryService = new DirectoryInfo();
          this.filService = new FileInfo();
    }

    // Injection Constructor
    public DocumentService(IDocumentDbService dbs, IDirectoryService ds, IFileService fs)
    {
         this.documentDService = dbs;
         this.directoryService = ds;
         this.fileService = fs;
    }
}
```

I use the second constructor to *mock* the dependencies for unit testing.

Some times there are too many dependencies, so the injection constructor would have too many parameters.

So, I want to use `Unity` dependency injection.

**Question**

How can I refactor this code to use `Unity` instead?

(After reading `Unity` documents, still not sure how to use it correctly on my codes.)

Comment: pretty sure you would use ***the exact same code*** for most DI frameworks.  You provide your dependencies at run time usually via a configuration file from a DI examples of what I've seen (Ninject, Unity, structuremap all have their own flavors/syntax for configuration).

Comment: You said you want to refactor this code to use unity instead. Instead of what?

Comment: Ditch the default constructor; having [multiple constructors is an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: I have been learning how to utilize Unity Containers as well and your question mirrors the type of Q&A I have been looking for; I hope somebody is able to clearly articulate an Answer for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to simplify unit test code to avoid manually setting up each dependency in every test:

You can setup container and add all necessary mocks there and than `Resolve` you class for the test like:

```
 // that initialization can be shared
 var container = new UnityContainer();
 // register all mocks (i.e. created with Moq)
 container.RegisterInstnce<IDocumentDbService>(Mock.Of<IDocumentDbService> ());

 // resolve your class under test 
 var documentService = container.Resolve<DocumentService>();

 Assert.AreEqual(42, documentService.GetSomething());
```

Answer (score 0):

I quess you want to inject dependencies in both situations: in (unit)tests (e.g. using RhinoMocks) and real implementation (using Unity). The refactoring implies in that case that you should remove the the first constructor (of class DocumentService). Needed configuration in your dependencies should be loaded inside the dependency itself: DocumentDbService, DirectoryInfo, FileInfo. More  information (like Dependency Injection Lifecycle) and some examples are available on MSDN, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx